# Trying to use PHP 'do-while' loop to find a random number

Tags: php, loops

I want to use PHP do while loop and find a random number.

Here is the code, it's not working...

```
<?php

$start = 10;
$end = 1;
$find = rand(0,9); 

do { 
 if ($start == $find):
   echo "Found!";
 elseif ($start != $find):
   echo $start; 
   $start = $start - $end;
 endif;
} while ($start != $find);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the last iteration, when with `$start = $start - $end;` the `$start` variable becomes equal to `$find`, you immediately get out of the loop (because `while ($start != $find);` is `false` in that moment). That's mean that

```
if ($start == $find):
     echo "Found!";
```

will never occur. If you understand this, then you understand that out of the loop `$start == $find` is always verified. So you can move that piece of code at the bottom:

```
$start = 10;
$end = 1;
$find = rand(0,9); 

do { 
    if ($start != $find): // ALWAYS true, can be omitted
        echo $start; 
        $start = $start - $end;
    endif;
} while ($start != $find);

if ($start == $find): // ALWAYS true, can be omitted
    echo "Found!";
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

*Federico* helped me to understand the errors so I will select his answer.

but, also here is my answer, explains what I was trying to achieve:

```
<?php

$start = 0;
$end = 1;
$find = 1;

do { 
    $find = rand($start,$end);
    echo $find."<br>";
} while ($start != $find);

if ($start == $find):
    echo "Found!";
endif;

?>
```

I'm planing to make the code work with a value taken from a `_REQUEST` so, actually the number won't be random. I just wanted to understand what was wrong and how 'do while' works using a `rand();` function first...